# What does "divine intervention" mean on the Sacred Wooden Katana?

Tags: yakuza-0

The description of the Sacred Wooden Katana states:

> This wooden sword is protected by the gods, and legend has it that divine intervention will occur when your health is low.

What does "divine intervention" mean in this context?

[image: Sacred Wooden Katana]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find its power in English, but I found the info on a [Japanese website](https://dswiipspwikips3.jp/yakuza0/weapon.html).

What you're using is called "神木の木刀" in the Japanese version. Its ability is, the more your health decreases, the more damage you can deal with this weapon. It's like the [Heroics](https://monsterhunterrise.wiki.fextralife.com/Heroics) skill in Monster hunter series.

So if you're fine with keeping your health low, you might probably can eliminate your enemies faster with this weapon.